# Bring in external data on BIM 360 model on forge platform

Tags: autodesk-forge, iot, autodesk-bim360

I want to do a project on bring in external data collected from batching plant IOT to the BIM 360 model of batching plant on forge platform so please guide me regarding it. which language  should use and if you guys have already something related to it so please share information with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample app might be helpful: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo ([live demo](https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io/)). It loads a design file from a specific location (which could be an existing design in BIM360 as well), and adds mocked-up IoT data to it in form of heatmaps, charts, etc.

If you're getting started with Autodesk Platform Services, I would suggest starting with https://tutorials.autodesk.io. As far as programming languages, you can use whatever language that can send HTTP requests, but most of the documentation and tooling we provide is for .NET and Node.js.

Comment: "Thank you so much for providing me with the solution!  could you please help me more regarding my project like what next step should i do and what type of data i can show on my model of batching plant

Comment: Once you have a basic application up and running, we can certainly talk about the specifics of your use case. Btw. we're planning another APS Online Bootcamp in October that might be helpful. Please monitor https://aps.autodesk.com/community-events for when it's announced.